# Show available updates immediately on login, not after 5 minutes

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 22.04

When I start my PC (Kubuntu 22.04) and log in, it checks for updates and, if there are any, shows a notification. However, this only happens after 5-10 minutes when I'm usually in the middle of something already. Then I have to drop everything I'm doing, update, and restart. Which is annoying and disruptive.

I'd like it to tell me immediately, before I have time to start doing anything else, if there are updates available.

I don't want it to tell me if there **aren't** any updates, so I don't want to simply open up Discover on startup.